# How to change css of class under specific id

Tags: html, css

I have This html i want to change the css of active class under abc_7 id.please help me.

```
<label id="abc_7" data-ng-repeat="cell in timeCell" class="btn btn-default btnsmall active" style="width: 77px;"> </label>
```

I have write this

```
#abc_7 .active{
background-color: green !important;

}
```

But it will not working because it will find active class with in #abc_7 lable please help me.

Answer (score 6):

You're specifying a child instead of the element that had the ID AND the class.

It should be: (note, no space between ID and class)

```
#abc_7.active{
   background-color: green;
}
```